# I am getting Employees with other dept also

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table in that i have millions of record i want a query that should return employees belongs to IT Dept and date of birth should be either null or 1970-01-01 or 1961-01-01 and employee status should be active.

I want result something like this

```
EmployeeID  Dept    Status  DateOfBirth
1           IT  Active  19600101
2           IT  Active  19700101
3           IT  Active  19600101
4           IT  Active  19700101
5           IT  Active  Null
6           IT  Active  Null
```

Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your query that gives the wrong result?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to supply a `WHERE` in you query which filters based on your condition.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Dept = 'IT' AND
        [Status] = 'Active' AND
        (
           DateOfBirth = 19700101 OR
           DateOfBirth = 19600101 OR
           DateOfBirth IS null
        )
```

Comment: When i am executing this code i am getting zero rows of get. I want all the employees who is active and dateofbirth either null or 19700101 or 19600101 and it should belongs to IT  dept and it should be active. Can you pls create to test table and try this code

Comment: @user2256481 You'll need to post your schema with the datatypes so it's possible to create a test table.

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active' AND DateOfBirth = null In this i am getting 0 row of data SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active' AND DateOfBirth is null I am executing this code i am getting 279 row of data SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active' AND DateOfBirth IN ('1970-01-01', '1961-01-01') I am executing this code i am getting 601 row of data So i should get 601+279 = 880 rows of data that i am not getting

Comment: EmployeeID int
Deptid int
Status varchar(20)
DateOfBirth int  This is the table structure

Comment: @user2256481 Hm, `Dept` is not even in your table. I give up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID,
    Dept,
    Status,
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
   yourTable
WHERE
    Dept = 'IT'
    AND Status = 'Active'
    AND (DateOfBirth IN (19700101, 19610101) OR DateOfBirth IS NULL)
```

Comment: whats the resultset u r getting?

Comment: SELECT 
    EmployeeID,
    Dept,
    Status,
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
   yourTable
WHERE
    Dept = 'IT'
    AND Status = 'Active'
    AND (DateOfBirth IN ('1970-01-01', '1961-01-01') OR DateOfBirth IS NULL) when i am executing this result i am getting 0 row od data.

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable
WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active'
AND DateOfBirth = null
In this i am getting 0 row of data
SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable
WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active'
AND DateOfBirth is null
I am executing this code i am getting 279 row of data
SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable
WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active'
AND DateOfBirth IN ('1970-01-01', '1961-01-01')
I am executing this code i am getting 601 row of data
So i should get 601+279 = 880 rows of data that i am not getting

Comment: @user2256481 from your above statements its sure that you didnt do whats mentioned in the above answer. u need to use both in a single query

Comment: @user2256481 and one more thing since your date datatype is int, i have updated the answer.please check. it will work for u.

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status, DateOfBirth
FROM yourTable
WHERE Dept = 'IT'
AND Status = 'Active'
AND (DateOfBirth IS NULL OR DateOfBirth IN (19700101, 19610101))     This code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers looks correct to me, but if they doesn't work for you then try with LIKE Keyword:

SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Dept Like '%IT%' AND
        [Status] Like  '%Active%' AND
        (
           DateOfBirth = 19700101 OR
           DateOfBirth = 19600101 OR
           DateOfBirth IS null
        )

If this doesnt work, please share your table structure.

Comment: this is returning zero rows of data

Comment: 1st: Check that such rows really exists!! 2nd: If exists, then start with one filter at a time example filter only DEPT first, then check results, then add other filter and check again.. do let us know the results\findings. This way you can know the issue, because above answers looks fine. Also, if you can tell us the table structure then we can help you futher! All the best!

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active' AND (DateOfBirth IN ('1970-01-01', '1961-01-01') OR DateOfBirth IS NULL)

Comment: EmployeeID int
Deptid int
Status varchar(20)
DateOfBirth int
This is table structure.

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth
FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT'
AND Status = 'Active' AND DateOfBirth = null

I am getting 0 row of data

SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth
FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT'
AND Status = 'Active' AND DateOfBirth is null

I am getting 279 row of data
SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth
FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT'
AND Status = 'Active'
AND DateOfBirth IN ('1970-01-01', '1961-01-01')

I am getting 601 row of data

So totally i should get 601+279 = 880 rows of data that i am not getting

Comment: If you are using INT as Date then dont put it in quotes. Try this : SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status,DateOfBirth FROM yourTable WHERE Dept = 'IT' AND Status = 'Active' AND (DateOfBirth IN (19700101,19600101) OR DateOfBirth IS NULL)

Comment: SELECT EmployeeID,Dept,Status, DateOfBirth
FROM yourTable
WHERE Dept = 'IT'
AND Status = 'Active'
AND (DateOfBirth IS NULL OR DateOfBirth IN (19700101, 19610101))       This code is working fine.